# select from a variable with html, with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html on a variable, how can I do a select on it and then an each on this variable? 
 Example:

```
var ht = '<div id="1" class="pp">Hi</div><div id="2">Hola</div><div id="3" class="pp"> Bonjour</div>';
$(ht).find(".pp").each( function(i){
   var i = this.id;
   console.log(i);
});
```

of course this does not work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have several sibling `.pp` elements that don't have a parent element.  When you create a jQuery object with them, it creates a selection containing each of the `.pp` elements.

When you use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), it looks at *descendant* elements.  The elements in the selection itself are not tested.  You need to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) instead, which tests the elements that are actually selected, not their descendants:

```
$(ht).filter(".pp").each( function(i){
   var i = this.id;
   console.log(i);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an element from your HTML, and then operate on the element:

Change:

```
var ht = '<div id="1" class="pp">Hi</div><div id="2">Hola</div><div id="3" class="pp"> Bonjour</div>';
```

to:

```
var ht = $('<div id="one" class="pp">Hi</div><div id="two">Hola</div><div id="three" class="pp"> Bonjour</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create these elements as jQuery objects:

```
var div0 = $('<div />');
var div1 = $('<div />').addClass('pp').text('Bonjour');
div0.append(div1);
div0.find('.pp'); // == div1
```

This is obviously not ideal code, but it should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: [Not true](http://jsfiddle.net/CVzwR/). This was indeed invalid before HTML5, but it works just fine.

Comment: @lonesomeday - interesting. i updated my answer. hopefully you can update your vote ;)

Comment: That hasn't really made your answer actually answer the question. You can build a jQuery object as the OP does -- you just need to make sure you're using the right traversing method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of `.find()`. You can't use find() as it looks for the matched elements in descendants of the selection, but you want to look among them instead.

```
var ht = '<div id="1" class="pp">Hi</div><div id="2">Hola</div><div id="3" class="pp"> Bonjour</div>';


$(ht).nextAll("div.pp").each( function(i){

   var i = this.id;
   console.log(i);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/dLL5r/